# Table is not Found while testing with H2Database

Tags: scala, h2, slick

I have been using slick for DB interaction and h2 in-memory database for testing.
So, I just added a new method where I have written plain SQL a query instead of a slick one.

Slick version: 3.3.0
HikariCp: 3.3.0
H2: 1.4.197

So it fails with the plain sql query with exception  `org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table \"TASK\" not found` even table is there.
For other test cases, we fetch data from the task table it works fine so the task table is there.

I cannot write a query in the slick for this method.

```
def filterTasksByGivenConstraints(taskIds: List[Long], constraints: String): Future[Vector[Int]] = {
    val ids = taskIds.mkString("'", "','", "'")
    val query = sql"""SELECT id FROM task WHERE id IN (#$ids) and #$constraints """.as[Int]
    db.get.run(query)
      .recover {
        case ex: Exception =>
          logger.error(s"An exception has occurred while fetching filtered tasks $ids for given constraints $constraints and exception is: $ex")
          throw ex
      }
  }
```

Comment: If you're sure that there is a table with a name `task`, you need to write it as `"task"` because with default settings of H2 `task` means `"TASK"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In H2 with its default settings identifiers are case-sensitive, but unquoted identifiers are converted to upper case. It means that table with real name `task` can only be referenced with quoted identifier `"task"`. Unquoted identifier `task` is equal to `"TASK"` and this is a different name.